# setCardElevation no effect pre Lollipop

Tags: android, material-design, android-cardview

setCardElevation has no effect for me on a 4.4 device - works on 5.0 - but from what I read in the documentation it should work on pre-L  - do you have to do something different than:

```
cardView.setCardElevation(8dp)
```

Comment: I don't think you can do this on pre-l (I hope I'm wrong lol..)

Comment: FYI: I set this in xml and it works on 4.4. ` card_view:cardElevation="8dp"`.

Answer (score 5):

Try using this:

```
cardview.setMaxCardElevation(8);
```

From the [CardView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html) docs:

> If you want to change elevation dynamically, you should call `setMaxCardElevation(float)` when `CardView` is initialized.

Comment: And I spend like some reasonable time looking for what is going wrong. Thanks a bunch. Glad this question was asked and answered already. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Fixed the issue instantly. Lucky that it was the first result of my google search :)